# Javascript - Object's property is determined by a function, node's not waiting for it

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have a fairly simple javascript/jquery obeject being built by a `Node.js` scraper. Everything works as it should (`obj.prod_name_select` and its counterparts return jquery selectors and they're parsing just fine in Node).

Here's the object:

```
var product = {
    name        : $(obj.prod_name_select).text(),
    systemName  : function(){
                    return product.name.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
                    },
    gender      : obj.gender,
    infoLink    : link,
    designer    : $(obj.label_name_select).first().text(),
    description : function(){
                    var text = $(obj.description).each(function() {
                                var content = $(this).contents();
                                $(this).replaceWith(content);
                            });
                    return text;
                    },
    price       : $(obj.price_select).first().text(),
    store       : obj.store,
    category    : obj.general_cat,
    spec_cat    : obj.spec_cat
}
console.log(product);
```

When I run this with Node, it's all working fine **except** for the properties being set by functions. These return `[FUNCTION]` in node. Here's the log from console:

```
{ name: 'BAGGY PANTS!T',
  systemName: [Function],
  gender: 'men',
  infoLink: 'http://www.hereisthecorrecturl.com',
  designer: 'Fancy Designer',
  description: [Function],
  price: '$180.00',
  store: 'Correct Store Name',
  category: 'Correct Category',
  spec_cat: 'Correct Category' }
```

Is this an asynchronous problem? It seems like the console.log is happening before the property functions are being run. What's the best way to solve this?

Comment: Um, they *are* the functions you assigned to the properties? You did not run them. Not sure what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of just assigning the function, you have to [immediately execute it](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/):

```
description : (function(){
    return $(obj.description).each(function() {
        var content = $(this).contents();
        $(this).replaceWith(content);
    });
}()),
```

Comment: Ah, this was simple. However, the issue when I invoke them immediately is that some properties rely on other properties being already set (see `product.systemName` above, which relies on `product.name` already being set, and I get an `undefined` error. What's the best practice here?

Comment: @Jascination: Execute it after the object is assigned to `product`. But why are you using functions at all?